# Monit doesn't run 'start program'

Tags: monit

I am trying to add one more process for monitoring through `monit`:

```
check process sidekiq_worker_flow with pidfile /home/flio/apps/stage-flow/current/tmp/pids/sidekiq-1.pid
  start program = "cd /home/flio/apps/stage-flow/current && source /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh && bundle exec sidekiq -i 1 -e staging --pidfile /home/flio/apps/stage-flow/current/tmp/pids/sidekiq-1.pid --logfile /home/flio/apps/stage-flow/shared/log/sidekiq-1.log --daemon" as uid flio
  stop program = "cd /home/flio/apps/stage-flow/current && bundle exec sidekiqctl stop /home/flio/apps/stage-flow/current/tmp/pids/sidekiq-1.pid 10" as uid flio
  if 5 restarts within 15 cycles then timeout
```

Looks like the command for 'start program' never called, because I've tried to call some debug command (echo 'bla bla' > ~/monint_debug.log') but never get anything.
I've also run commands (under root) for start and stop manually - and it works properly.
I also have another similar script:

```
check process sidekiq_worker_2
  with pidfile /var/www/flio/current/tmp/pids/sidekiq-1.pid
  start program = "/bin/su -lc 'cd /var/www/flio/current && source /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh && bundle exec sidekiq -i 1 -e production --pidfile /var/www/flio/current/tmp/pids/sidekiq-1.pid --logfile /var/www/flio/shared/log/sidekiq-1.log --daemon -C /var/www/flio/current/config/sidekiq_2.yml' flio"
  stop program = "/bin/su -lc 'cd /var/www/flio/current && bundle exec sidekiqctl stop /var/www/flio/current/tmp/pids/sidekiq-1.pid 10' flio"
  if 5 restarts within 15 cycles then timeout
```

and it works fine.

Comment: monit runs as root, why the su?

Comment: does monit have a log you can check for errors or warnings?

Comment: Also, noticed you've used different syntaxes for the two scripts.. for the working script you're using `su` to start the command with a certain user, while in the first (not working) one you're using some monit syntax `as uid flio`, are you sure that should work that way?

Comment: @Fanatique, I've tried to use the same syntax for the first script but got the fail and after that, I've changed to monit syntax with hope that can help.

Comment: Strange but I've returned the old variant (like in the second script) only add redirect output to a file and it starts to work. Need restart monit when changing configs?

Comment: @kunashir You need to do restart in many running Unix daemons when changing configs, monit included.

Comment: Maybe it was my problem - I did only `monit start my_service` but it didn't use the updated config file.